# Define a region in using MaxValue[] function in Mathematica

Tags: max, wolfram-mathematica, mathematica-8

The following two gives completely different output from Mathematica.
The online document does not seem to require a pair of curly braces.
https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MaxValue.html

```
Tau = 10;
Diff = 1/3;
phi[tau_] := 0.5 Sin[Pi tau/(Tau + 2 Diff)] + 0.5 Sin[Pi (tau + 2 Diff)/(Tau + 2 Diff)];
In[1]=MaxValue[phi[tau], {tau} \[Element] Interval[{0.0, 10.0}]]
In[2]=MaxValue[phi[tau], tau \[Element] Interval[{0.0, 10.0}]]
```

Output:

```
Output[1]=0.995185

MaxValue::objfs: The objective function {0.5 Sin[(3 \[Pi] Subscript[tau, 1])/32]+0.5 Sin[3/32 \[Pi] (2/3+Subscript[tau, <<1>>])]} should be scalar-valued. >>

Out[2]=MaxValue[0.5 Sin[(3 \[Pi] tau)/32] + 0.5 Sin[3/32 \[Pi] (2/3 + tau)], tau \[Element] Interval[{-2.22507*10^-308, 10.}]]
```

Comment: I would call that a discrepancy in the documentation.

Comment: Are you saying that the brace set is necessary, but omitted in the document?

Comment: the docs don't give any example of a single variable `MaxValue` / `Element` usage. Evidently the brackets are required and the docs should say so.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation does specify that you need curly braces when using the *region specification* method to define the constrains.  In the **Details and Options** section fourth method of defining constraints with a *region specification* shows that the curly brackets are necessary.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Good catch! Thanks! Apparently this is not documented consistently everywhere.